# codekit sass/css minify with compass installed on project

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, codekit

I wonder how can I solve to make my project output css file to compile in compressed format, cause there is not an option for that if i install compass to my project[image]

The option should be on the right hand column, but there isnt. I also did choosen the output style: compressed in codekit preferences for sass/scss.
Note again I have problems with output compress only when compass is installed on my project.

**P.S:** anyone know a good snippet collection for sccs -> compass? for sublime text 2

Answer (score 2):

Ohh i found out how to solve it, in config.rb file:

```
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
fonts_dir = "fonts"

output_style = :nested
```

if i edit the output_style directly from there it will work just fine with compass, just make :compressed

anyways im still curious if there is a good snippet vocabulary for compass @includes (mixins)

Comment: [Compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/) itself has *lots* of mixins.